# Amounts of various oils in hops.

Tags: beer, hops

I have a [beautiful chart](http://zekeshore.com/hops_v1.12.png) that shows the level of various hop oils in different hops, as well as their typical alpha acid percentages.  Where can I find the raw data that would go into a chart like this?  I am interested in making an interactive version of that chart.  Also, there is at least one hop oil not measured in that chart. (cohumulone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been trying to [compile a sourced- and rolled-up list of hops](https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjCpyKuDBP1TdFNiT1ctTFZVeGtRQ3hpSkxfTUgwZnc&hl=en_US&authkey=CJiF3NcN) for a project ([brew-journal.com](http://brew-journal.com)).  Data is very commercially driven, and hard to come by.   Feel free to use (look for the green-annotated "COMBINED" rows) and please let me know if you find another/appropriate source to be included.

Answer (score 2):

Pick up a copy of Designing Great Beers. For an advanced homebrewer book, it gets real deep into 4 or so different types of oils, how isomerization in the boil works, etc.

The book is 2 halves... background science and research, plus a study of AHA competition winning beers. The AHA competition part is a little dated, but the other half of the book... great beer geek science.

You could also write to FreshHops... they have access to a lot of information.